# ASP.net 3.5 site needs streaming video

Tags: asp.net-3.5, video-streaming, wmv

I maintain an ASP.net 3.5 website for a client who is now wanting to include short informational videos inline on certain pages of his site.  He is hosted with Network Solutions on a shared account.  I setup video services on his account and have been provided with an IP address to reference in an  tag.  However, the video needs to play upon page load, rather than play when user clicks a link to it.

Can anyone suggest a plugin or Javascript library that will allow videos to be played upon page load?  All video files will be saved in .wmv format.

Thanks,
Sid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SilverLight should be able to do that.

http://www.85turns.com/2008/04/02/create-a-video-player-silverlight-2-part-1/

Comment: I will check into Silverlight.  It's not so much that I need a video player plugin, rather that the video needs to load when the page loads.  That is, the video needs to start playing when the page loads into the browser, not when the user presses a "Play" button.

Answer (score 1):

Chek out jw player
http://www.longtailvideo.com/players/jw-flv-player/